# Nested for loop in C# that needs to get object data from multiple class files

Tags: c#

I have 3 models that i have given 2 objects of static data each. The models are 'TransactionLine1', 'TransactionLine2', 'TransactionLine3'.

**TransactionLine1.cs**

```
public class TransactionLine1
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static readonly TransactionLine1 T1 = new TransactionLine1
        {
            Id = "10",
            Name = "TL11"
        };

        public static readonly TransactionLine1 T2 = new TransactionLine1
        {
            Id = "11",
            Name = "TL12"
        };

        public static List<TransactionLine1> TransactionsL01
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(TransactionLine1).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Select(f => (TransactionLine1)f.GetValue(null))
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
```

**TransactionLine2.cs**

```
public class TransactionLine2
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static readonly TransactionLine2 T1 = new TransactionLine2
        {
            Id = "10",
            Name = "TL21"
        };

        public static readonly TransactionLine2 T2 = new TransactionLine2
        {
            Id = "11",
            Name = "TL22"
        };

        public static List<TransactionLine2> TransactionsL01
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(TransactionLine2).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Select(f => (TransactionLine2)f.GetValue(null))
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
```

**TransactionLine3.cs**

```
public class TransactionLine3
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static readonly TransactionLine3 T1 = new TransactionLine3
        {
            Id = "10",
            Name = "TL31"
        };

        public static readonly TransactionLine3 T2 = new TransactionLine3
        {
            Id = "11",
            Name = "TL32"
        };

        public static List<TransactionLine3> TransactionsL01
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(TransactionLine3).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Select(f => (TransactionLine3)f.GetValue(null))
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
```

Now i want to loop through each file and write the fields to the console. However i need to to be done in the order of the objects by transaction line. So it must go:

```
T1 Line1 (from TransactionLine1.cs)
T1 Line2 (from TransactionLine2.cs)
T1 Line3 (from TransactionLine3.cs)

T2 Line1 (from TransactionLine1.cs)
T2 Line2 (from TransactionLine2.cs)
T2 Line3 (from TransactionLine3.cs)
```

I can use a foreach to step through each object for a specific class file. But how could i do it for all of them to get the desired output? Im new to C# and am struggling a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the actual problem behind the given example so I can't advise anything smarter to optimize the structure of your classes themselves. However, you could create an array of types of classes you want to loop through and select their fields as well as their field indices and then order the selected result by field index and type index in that particular order.

Take a look at this example:

```
var types = new Type[]
{
    typeof(TransactionLine1),
    typeof(TransactionLine2),
    typeof(TransactionLine3)
};

List<object> items = types
    .SelectMany((type, typeIndex) =>
        type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Select((field, fieldIndex) => new
            {
                TypeIndex = typeIndex,
                FieldIndex = fieldIndex,
                Field = field.GetValue(null)
            }))
    .OrderBy(item => item.FieldIndex)
    .ThenBy(item => item.TypeIndex)
    .Select(item => item.Field)
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items));
```

Of course, you should also override the `ToString` method in your classes in order to get the meaningful output instead of an object reference.

```
public override string ToString() => $"Id: {Id}, Name: {Name}";
```

Using the code from the example you've provided, I'm getting the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```cs
for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                // =====Writing T1=====
                switch(j) {
                   case 1:
                       Console.WriteLine("TL1:\nT1 ID: " + TransactionLine1.T1.Id); // TL1
                       Console.WriteLine("TL1:\nT1 Name: " + TransactionLine1.T1.Name);
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       Console.WriteLine("TL2:\nT1 ID: " + TransactionLine2.T1.Id); // TL2
                       Console.WriteLine("TL2:\nT1 Name: " + TransactionLine2.T1.Name);
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       Console.WriteLine("TL3:\nT1 ID: " + TransactionLine3.T1.Id); // TL3
                       Console.WriteLine("TL3:\nT1 Name: " + TransactionLine3.T1.Name);
                       break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                // =====Writing T2=====
                switch(j) {
                   case 1:
                       Console.WriteLine("TL1:\nT2 ID: " + TransactionLine1.T2.Id); // TL1
                       Console.WriteLine("TL1:\nT2 Name: " + TransactionLine1.T2.Name);
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       Console.WriteLine("TL2:\nT2 ID: " + TransactionLine2.T2.Id); // TL2
                       Console.WriteLine("TL2:\nT2 Name: " + TransactionLine2.T2.Name);
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       Console.WriteLine("TL3:\nT2 ID: " + TransactionLine3.T2.Id); // TL3
                       Console.WriteLine("TL3:\nT2 Name: " + TransactionLine3.T2.Name);
                       break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
TL1:
T1 ID: 10
TL1:
T1 Name: TL11
TL2:
T1 ID: 10
TL2:
T1 Name: TL21
TL3:
T1 ID: 10
TL3:
T1 Name: TL31
TL1:
T2 ID: 11
TL1:
T2 Name: TL12
TL2:
T2 ID: 11
TL2:
T2 Name: TL22
TL3:
T2 ID: 11
TL3:
T2 Name: TL32
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Not sure if this would work if i were pulling actual data from my DB, which may be hundreds of lines of transactions. Although the example is using static data it should be able to handle a variable number of transactions. LMK if i'm completely wrong?

Comment: 3 minutes earlier it wasn't working, now it is.
And sorry, it doesn't work with a variable number of transactions... :(